# Multiple File Stream Issue

Tags: python, file-io, python-module

In my project, I am using 3 files throughout the whole process. The source file (.ada), a "three address code" file (.TAC), and my own temporary file for use during processing (.TACTMP).

in Caller.py:

```
TACFILE = open(str(sys.argv[1])[:-4] + ".TAC", 'w') # line 17
# Does a bunch of stuff
TACFILE.close() # line 653
# the below function is imported from Called.py
post_process_file_handler() # line 654
```

in Called.py:

```
TAC_FILE_NAME = str(sys.argv[1])[:-4] # line 6
TAC_lines = open(TAC_FILE_NAME + ".TAC", 'r').readlines() # line 7
```

If I try to run my program without already having a (even if it's blank) .TAC file, I will get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Caller.py", line 8, in <module>
    from Called import post_process_file_handler
  File "Called.py", line 7, in <module>
    TAC_lines = file(TAC_FILE_NAME + ".TAC", 'r').readlines()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test76.TAC'
```

Why would this be happening? This error is being thrown even if I put a breakpoint at the beginning of Caller.py, well before the `post_process_file_handler()` function ever gets called.

For clarity: test76.TAC should be being generated by Caller.py, and then Called.py should open that file to process it further, for some reason that isn't happening.

Comment: You cannot open a nonexistent file for reading. You must first check if it exists, or be prepared to catch the `IOError` exception.

Comment: @DYZ that's where I'm a bit confused though. Calling.py is to create this file and then close it before it even calls the function that is opening it to read it, how is it possible that it's happening out of order?

Comment: It is not clear from your example in which order the functions are called. Please update. It is also not clear where the function `file` comes from, as there is no built-in function with such name. Please update.

Comment: @DYZ That is actually weird... It should be `open`. I don't know where `file` came from, but it compiles, runs, and works in a quick example I just tried haha. Anyways, I've added line numbers to the code snippets

Comment: Did you check if test76.TAC actually exists?

Comment: That's my point, it shouldn't have to exist. It's a file being generated by `Caller.py`, and then `Called.py` should be able to open test76.TAC to process it. The `'w'` flag in python should create the file if it doesn't exist and still write out to it, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be specific to my case, but I found out the issue is due to the order and manner in which I was using these streams.

In short, when the import line was encountered:

```
from Called import post_process_file_handler
```

it triggered some sort of initialization, and since the file pointer was a global variable in Called.py, it was initialized before Caller.py had a chance to create the .TAC file it would read from.

Moving the import line to just before I use the function fixed my issue, as nothing in Called.py is initialized until after Caller.py is done doing its work.